# expanding partition with available space

Tags: partition

I do not want to destroy my vm :) I am new at linux (start up on a budget)

Here are my partitions:

```
Filesystem                   Size     Used      Avail   Use%     Mounted on
udev                         3.9G     0         3.9G    0%       /dev
tmpfs                        798M     924K      797M    1%       /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root      4.6G     3.9G      442M    90%      /
tmpfs                        3.9G     8.0K      3.9G    1%       /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0         5.0M    0%       /run/lock
tmpfs                        3.9G     0         3.9G    0%       /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-tmp       453M     2.3M      423M    1%       /tmp
/dev/sda1                    990M     145M      779M    16%      /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-home      1.8G     128M      1.6G    8%       /home
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-var       2.7G     1.4G      1.2G    55%      /var
tmpfs                        798M     0         798M    0%       /run/user/1000

total                        24G      5.5G      18G     24%      -
```

It looks like I should have close to 400GB but my partitions total ("total" above) shows 24GB

I am nearly out of partition space on `/` and need to expand it:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root 4.6G 3.9G 442M 90% /
```

When looking at my virtual disk sizes:

```
H/W path           Device      Class      Description
=====================================================
/0/100/10/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk       1073MB Virtual disk
/0/100/10/0.1.0    /dev/sdb    disk       284GB Virtual disk
/0/100/10/0.3.0    /dev/sdd    disk       107GB Virtual disk
```

How do I know what is on `/dev/sdb`?

How do I know what is on `/dev/sdd`?

Is that just free space?

How do I expand `/`?

---

requested info:

```
 NAME          MAJ:MIN   RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 fd0             2:0      1    4K  0 disk
 sda             8:0      0    1G  0 disk
 └─sda1          8:1      0 1022M  0 part /boot
 sdb             8:16     0  265G  0 disk
 sdc             8:32     0   50G  0 disk
 ├─ubuntu-root   253:0    0  4.7G  0 lvm  /
 ├─ubuntu-swap   253:1    0  1.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
 ├─ubuntu-tmp    253:2    0  476M  0 lvm  /tmp
 ├─ubuntu-home   253:3    0  1.9G  0 lvm  /home
 └─ubuntu-var    253:4    0  2.8G  0 lvm  /var
 sdd             8:48     0  100G  0 disk
 sr0             11:0     1 1024M  0 rom
```

---

after applying solution

```
 fd0               2:0    1     4K  0 disk
 sda               8:0    0     1G  0 disk
 └─sda1            8:1    0  1022M  0 part /boot
 sdb               8:16   0   265G  0 disk
 └─sdb1            8:17   0   265G  0 part
   ├─ubuntu-root 253:0    0 204.7G  0 lvm  /
   ├─ubuntu-home 253:3    0   7.9G  0 lvm  /home
   └─ubuntu-var  253:4    0  22.8G  0 lvm  /var
 sdc               8:32   0    50G  0 disk
 ├─ubuntu-root   253:0    0 204.7G  0 lvm  /
 ├─ubuntu-swap   253:1    0   1.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
 ├─ubuntu-tmp    253:2    0   476M  0 lvm  /tmp
 ├─ubuntu-home   253:3    0   7.9G  0 lvm  /home
 └─ubuntu-var    253:4    0  22.8G  0 lvm  /var
 sdd               8:48   0   100G  0 disk
 sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please add `lsblk` output to your question.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny added lsblk result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `sdb` and `sdd` drives seems to be unused. You are using LVM, so you first need to add these drives to your existing volume group and then resize the `root` (or `home` or `var` logical volumes).

- Create partitions on `sdb` and `sdd` using `fdisk` (it's an interactive tool, just run `fdisk /dev/sdb`, use `n` to add new partition, accept all defaults for start, size etc. and use `w` to write changes, repeat for `/dev/sdd`).
- Create physical volume on the new partitions `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`, `pvcreate /dev/sdd1`.
- Add the physical volumes to your *ubuntu* volume group using `vgextend ubuntu /dev/sdb1`, `vgextend ubuntu /dev/sdd1`
- Resize your `root` logical volume `lvresize -L+100G -r ubuntu/root` (this will grow your `root` volume by 100 GiB, adjust the number based on your needs, you might want to resize `var` and `home` as well).

Based on the filesystem you are using, you might need to do the last step from a LiveCD, some filesystems can't be resized while in use (and it's generally better to do storage operations on inactive devices).
And don't forget to make a backup in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I applied your solution. (didn't use all the unallocated space yet) How does it look?

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step, very appreciated

Comment: It looks good. You don't need to use all empty space, you can keep some space unused for future changes.